# Как объединить два столбца в один?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица, в которой поиск всегда происходит по двум столбцам - `origin` и `destination`. Значения столбцов представляют собой трёхзначную строку - `MOW`, `LED` и т.д. В таблице хранится порядка 50.000 записей и запросы к ней выполняются по 2 секунды. Для ускорения запросов придумал следующий алгоритм:

1. Создаём новый столбец под названием `key`. В него записываем значения из полей `origin` и `destination`, разделяя их прочерком. Получается запись вида `MOW-LED`, которая всегда будет уникальной.
2. Создаём уникальный индекс (`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX`) для таблицы по значению новосозданного столбца `key`

Как это можно сделать одним SQL-запросом?

Comment: Зачем? почему не сделать два текущих поля - индексами? зы. для информации https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/indexes-multicolumn

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков разве поиск не будет ещё быстрее, если искать по одному столбцу, а не по двум?

Comment: Нет не будет, делаете составной индекс, и в нем поиск будет идти как по одному полю(обновил комментарий выше, ссылка на описание)

Comment: Дополню еще момент - составной индекс может быть уникальным(`UNIQUE`) что даст еще плюс к точному поиску....

Comment: *Значения столбцов представляют собой трёхзначную строку - MOW, LED и т.д.* 18 тыс. вариантов для одного поля, 300 млн. для двух. Т.е. два поля прекрасно пакуются в одно типа INT. Индексирование - проще некуда. Упаковка-распаковка - элементарная.